# how to stop Visual Studio from left aligning pasted text in a block comment?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

In VS2015, copying and pasting a C/C++ block comment left-aligns all text within the block comment.  How do I disable or change this functionality?  For example, all text in the following block comment is indented one tab (or the equivalent number of spaces).

```
/*
    first line of comment
    second line of comment
*/
```

If I copy and paste this block comment then all text is left aligned to the comment delimiters so that it appears as follows:

```
/*
first line of comment
second line of comment
*/
```

Now, if all code in a file is selected (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>), deleted (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>) and then pasted (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) then VS2015 automatically re-formats all of the code in the file.   This is a particularly useful feature.   However doing so causes all text within block comments to be left aligned with the block comment delimiters - a feature I wish to disable.

Is there a way to copy-and-paste text in VS2015 such that text in block comments are not left-aligned with the block comment delimiters?

Thanks

Comment: I've never seen that effect, but then (1) I don't use block comments, and (2) I've turned off as much of the automatic We Know Better Than You™ stuff as I could. Go to options. Turn off stuff.

Comment: No luck.   I've tried disabling pretty much all available options and none seem to do the trick.   Also, the problem occurs even when each line starts with double forward slashes ( `//`), three forward slashes (`///`) and four forward slashes (`////`).  What type of comments are you using and are you saying the problem I described does not occur on your system for the comment format you use?

Comment: Doesn't happen with my VS 2015 update 2. I guess that's because in Options > Formatting > When I Paste I've chosen Do Nothing. :) You can always explicitly request reformatting of the document.

Comment: Chuckle!   That definitely works.  But, would you mind doing me a favor and set the Formatting option to `Indent and format` and seeing if you get the same effect I reported?   It would be very helpful knowing what happens on your system.